# Find the most repeated word in a folder

Tags: linux, grep

Is there a way in linux to find the most repeated word in files of current folder and childs.
I need this to find the most used c++ classes in my project.
The output could be like this :

```
class alpha : 157,
class beta  : 98,
class gamma : 13,
...
```

**means 157 references to the class alpha etc ...**

Can this be done using a Linux command (maybe grep) ? or Should I use a tool for this ?

Comment: "Can this be done" is always the wrong question for a turing-complete language like `bash`... Of course, it can be done. The only question is: at what cost? Do I care enough to code it? Am I patient enough to wait for the answer?

Comment: In general you can't find class names in files of code using tools that do not understand the language the code is written in (in `class foo` is `foo` a class name? What if it was `// class foo`? What if it was `char *a="class foo";`?), but see http://beyondgrep.com/ and http://cscope.sourceforge.net/ for possible help.

Comment: @EdMorton You are right, but I don't actually need the exact number of references, an approximation is enough for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to find the most used words within the files, you can use

```
grep -hoE "\w+" * | sort | uniq -c | sort -g
```

This counts all words as your question asked for.

```
grep -hoE "\w{7,}" * | sort | uniq -c | sort -g
```

This counts words that are longer than six characters.

Comment: How can I modify this to get the classes references ?? or maybe only choosing words which size is larger than a minimum size ?

Comment: sorry, I simply don't know how to detect a class reference in C++ source files.

Comment: okay can I add a minimal size of words then ? and also give it a list of words I don't want to show ?

Comment: I give this a last trial: assuming your file with the words you don't want is called `not.these`, you can pipe the command above into `grep -vf not.these`